# SQLITE selecting between tables

Tags: sqlite

This is blatantly a homework assignment, but I want to know how to do this one so that I can do the rest.
 "Write an SQL select command to produce the titles of all the musicals authored by Oscar Hammerstein."
I try " select title from musicals, authors where authors.name="Oscar Hammerstein"; "
It returns all the titles for the musicals.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query is using a [CROSS JOIN aka CARTESIAN PRODUCT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Cross_join).

The `r1, r2` operator is the *same* as writing `r1 CROSS JOIN r2` like this:

```
select title
from musicals CROSS JOIN authors
where authors.name="Oscar Hammerstein"
```

Either increase the specificity in the WHERE or, my recommendation, use an [INNER [Equi-]JOIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Equi-join).

```
select title
from musicals
JOIN authors                      -- just JOIN means INNER JOIN
ON musicals.author = author.name  -- join on related data, adjust to schema
where authors.name = "Oscar Hammerstein"
```

---

The same rules apply for a query across a [many-many joining table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table). Using the schema in the comments:

```
select m.title
from authors_musicals am           -- from all authors/musical pairs
    -- as opposed to authors CROSS JOIN musicals, the M-M joining table
    -- only has the actual author/musical pair combinations
join authors a                     -- choose the author
on a.id = am.author_id
join musicals m                    -- and the musical
on m.id = am.musical_id
where a.name = 'Oscar Hammerstein' -- where the author has a given name
```

(Also, I recommend using `'ANSI SQL quotes'`, even if SQLite will accept `"MySQL quotes"`.)

Comment: That gave the same result.

Comment: @user2824852 The `CROSS JOIN` and `,` will as they are the *same* operation. The INNER JOIN bellow will definitely not give the same result. I've edited the response for clarity.

Comment: ah, thank you. My bad. 
That bit of code gives me "Error: no such column: musicals.author" The tables are "musicals" and "author"

Comment: @user2824852 Yeah, I don't know what your schema looks like - use the correct column name. If there is a joining table, then use that in the query of course.

Comment: schema is:                                                          CREATE TABLE "authors" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL , "name" VARCHAR);
CREATE TABLE "authors_musicals" ("author_id" INTEGER,"musical_id" INTEGER);
CREATE TABLE "musicals" ("id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL , "title" VARCHAR, "year" INTEGER);

Comment: @user2824852 Yes, you have a joining table (author_musicals); join this to BOTH other relations (using an INNER JOIN). This information is *very important* in writing a query and should be including in the post (not buried in a comment or outright omitted!)

Comment: I'm sorry, i'm completely lost now.

Comment: @user2824852 With what? Being lost is fine, but you have to be explicit about where the confusion lies .. barring a simple mistake on my part (or bad information in the database), the query I added to the end of my reply should accomplish your task. So what confusion does it create?

Comment: @user2824852 If a response answers the question(s) suitably you can click on the "check box". It should be next/to or below the voting arrows to the top-left of the answer.

Comment: So, just wondering. What you did was give the columns abbreviations, as part of the solution, right? I just want to understand How it works.

Comment: @user2824852 Because I'm lazy *and* I like to be explicit (i.e. I manually specified `m.title` and `a.name` instead of relying on `title` and `name` being unique in the query). So, even though [*aliases*](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html) are generally not required, I would much rather type `am.author_id` than `authors_musicals.author_id` where such qualification is required and thus I do so as a general practice for consistency and familiarity. (I also usually omit the 'AS', but some people find it more clear as `FROM authors AS a ..`)